# Installed new Pypi module looks OK but not recognised by python?

Tags: python, pypi, sdist

I'm having trouble with a Python package on PyPi.  I can't see any answered questions for problems like this (though I've found some unanswered ones), so here goes:

My package BrickPython looks like this:

```
BrickPython
    + BrickPython
        + __init__.py
        + Scheduler.py
    + Other test and example modules at top level.
```

The module has a working setup.py; package BrickPython appears to be correctly installed on PyPi (using python setup.py sdist upload); and

```
sudo pip install BrickPython
```

completes successfully.   However when I attempt to use it, I see errors:

```
>>> import BrickPython
>>> BrickPython.Motor
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Motor'
```

As far as I can see I'm following the setup similar to http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html#directory-layout (for all the test code is in a different place), so I'm wondering what can be wrong.  It's painful to experiment with this, as apparently I have to make a new release to test each change I make.

Please,

1) How can I experiment with egg package installation without going through PyPi installations?

2) What should I do to make it work?

- Charles

Comment: Do you have `BrickPython/BrickPython/Motor.py` file? Do you import `BrickPython.Motor` in `BrickPython/BrickPython/__init__.py`?

Comment: *"How can I experiment with egg package installation without going through PyPi installations?"* run `pip install -e .` in the directory with `setup.py`.

Comment: Aha, great!  Thank you J.F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
from BrickPython import Motor

m = Motor.Motor(<port>, [scheduler])
```

Comment: Yes - that works.  My misunderstanding of Python import syntax.  More usually it would become `from BrickPython.Motor import Motor ...  m=Motor(0)`.  Many thanks!  

- Charles